# ¿Por qué django no me reconoce los archivos estáticos?

Tags: javascript, css, python-3.x, django

He estado siguiendo un tutorial para aprender a utilizar django, y he seguido los pasos de este, e incluso leí la parte de archivos estáticos en la documentación de django... tengo guardado los archivos css y js dentro de las carpetas que decía el tutorial y como explicaba la guía.

[image: Aquí está la carpeta en donde los guardé]

Y revisé las etiquetas y creo que están bien:

[image: Aquí esta la parte del código en donde le colocó las etiquetas a los archivos css]

La cosa es, que cuando inicio el servidor, no me reconoce los archivos css ni de javascript, y no sé qué hacer... La versión que estoy utilizando de django es la 3.0.4, mi editor es spyder 4 y estoy usando python 3.7.6

Comment: Te aseguraste de registrar la ruta en el archivo `settings.py`?

Comment: ¿Debo registrar la ruta de los archivos estáticos? Solo tengo al final lo que genera automáticamente de: STATIC_URL = '/static/'

Comment: ¿Cómo la registro?

Comment: Despues de esa constante utiliza esta `STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)`